# What's the best way to support mosh behind NAT to multiple hosts?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, udp, mosh

Mosh requires that you port forward UDP ports 60000 to 61000 to your host (unless you specify different ports.)

If you have three hosts behind NAT, for instance, that you want usable with mosh, how can you do so with the least amount of tediousness?

Client side configuration should be avoided, as it will be much easier to configure just a few hosts rather than a bunch of clients.

Could there be a way to configure each server to use specific mosh ports?